# Blender 2.82 Smoke/fire not working in a specific file

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

[image][image][image][image]I'm still new to Blender and am currently following the donut tutorial. Close to finishing the whole series, I figured i'd try to set up some light smoke over the coffee cup. 
I have already worked out how to use "Quick smoke" and know how to bake the simulation through the smoke domain. I created a plane over the coffee mesh, used quicked smoke on it. However, after baking (at least my computer *seems* to bake), nothing shows up. 
I have tried several new meshes and planes (circle, cube, monkey) but none seem to work, even when not tweaking anything.
The smoke does not show in any shading mode nor in the renders.
I have created a new file and it works perfectly fine. 
I suppose I may have checked or unchecked something somewhere but I didn't find any answer anywhere!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post an image

Comment: can you post a screenshot in render mode

Comment: I believe that's what you asked, It's my first post here so please forgive the chaotic look of it. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: can you redo it and check whether it is working in a new file

Comment: It works perfectly in a new file.

Comment: can you show me your domain settings